# Angular / Resize-Base64 - Failed to execute 'drawImage'

Tags: angular, base64, image-resizing

I'm using 'Resize-base64' (https://github.com/dizhar/resize-base64) in Angular. When I pass a base64 string, I console logged in the script to double check the values were correctly received. They were. However, when it get's to 'var img = newImage()', it creates the image, but it seems to take a few seconds to populate the src attribute with the base64 string. So when I console log 'img.width and height', they are all returned as '0', therefore, throwing the error:

> Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0.

Is there a way to ensure that the src attribute is populated before the rest of the script runs? Or, is there an obvious reason for the error that I'm missing?

**My Angular Component**

```
setLargeImageDimensions(resetBase64Image) {
   var img = resizebase64(resetBase64Image, 1000, 1000); 
}
```

**The 'Resize-Base64 Node Module / Script**

```
module.exports = function(base64, maxWidth, maxHeight){
  console.log('base64 = ', base64);
  console.log('maxWidth = ', maxWidth);
  console.log('maxHeight = ', maxHeight);

  // Max size for thumbnail
  if(typeof(maxWidth) === 'undefined')  maxWidth = 500;
  if(typeof(maxHeight) === 'undefined')  maxHeight = 500;

  // Create and initialize two canvas
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var canvasCopy = document.createElement("canvas");
  var copyContext = canvasCopy.getContext("2d");
  var canvasID = canvas.setAttribute('id', 'resize-base64');



  // Create original image
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = base64;

  // Determine new ratio based on max size
  var ratio = 1;
  if(img.width > maxWidth)
     ratio = maxWidth / img.width;
  else if(img.height > maxHeight)
     ratio = maxHeight / img.height;


 // Draw original image in second canvas
 canvasCopy.width = img.width;
 canvasCopy.height = img.height;
 copyContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

 // Copy and resize second canvas to first canvas
 canvas.width = img.width * ratio;
 canvas.height = img.height * ratio;
 console.log('   canvas.width = ',    canvas.width);
 console.log('  canvas.height  = ',   canvas.width );
 ctx.drawImage(canvasCopy, 0, 0, canvasCopy.width, canvasCopy.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


 return maxWidth;
}
```

Comment: Do you load this into the DOM in any way or is it just a "virtual" image?

Comment: Hi @Chrillewoodz - I'm guessing it's virtual? I just updated my original post with how I call it from my Angular component. The script is from the resize-base64 node module. I console logged everything I could and all the canvas widths & heights returned as 0. But what I did notice is that when I try to console log the img.src, that get's populated AFTER all the img.height logs are returned.

Comment: What if you set the src using Renderer2? `this.renderer.setAttribute(img, 'src', base64);`

Comment: Inside the `Resize-Base64` script? I'm not familiar with renderer. How would that be different to what the script is trying to do with 'img.src = base64'?

Comment: Ah nvm you can't inject it there, would need a service or a way to inject it. It would add the attribute within the angular environment which would make sure things run in a correct order, or you end up with bugs like this one.

Comment: I've figured out to get the dimensions back properly now, which is a good start. The only issue now is that it's returning a blank PNG opposed to a resized image.